# Distributed training on CPU's multiple cores in Keras

Tags: keras, distributed-computing

According to what I read in different posts and blogs and my limited trials, it looks like both Tensorflow and Keras use as many CPU cores available on an individual machine. That makes sense (and is indeed very nice) but does it mean that Keras will do distributed training across multiple cores? This is the thing that I want to do: I have a moderate model but large dataset and want to distribute learning of different batches between cores. I don't have much knowledge on parallel and distributed processing, but I just guess that a distributed learning requires some additional handling of data and gradient calculation and aggregation on top of basic multithreading/ multitasking. Does Keras do such a thing automatically when using different cores of the same CPU in an individual machine? How can I check it?

And if I want to go further and use multiple computers for distributed training, what everybody refers to is at https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed .
But it is a bit complicated and doesn't mention anything about Keras in specific. Is there any other source that specifically discusses distributed training of Keras models over Tensorflow?